# Will my app be rejected on Play Store or App Store because it is based on a WebView?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, google-play, app-store

I am working on to create a Xamarin Forms app (For Android and iOS both) which will have payment gateway to accept payments from customers. Currently I am using WebView in my app to open the payment page URL. So, my question is that will my app be rejected on Play Store or Apple Store because it is based on WebView? If yes, then is there any alternative to WebView?

Comment: Hi , do you need to open another app to complish the payment ?

Comment: No, I would prefer to to accept the payment in my own app.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on Apple's review process. If the whole app is just a WebView pointing to a website, then it is likely to be rejected. If the app has other features and functionality of its own, especially utilizing native device functionality, then it will have a better chance of being accepted in the stores.

See [App Store Review Guidelines Section 4.2](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#design).