# Can you publish xamarin app containing a webview in Playstore/Appstore?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, google-play, app-store

I have a question regarding the AppStore rejection of a Xamarin iOS app.
Our app consists of 2 sections, a section which contains a WebView containing our web app and the other section contains a native UI page about applying settings for the application. I am aware about the AppStore Review Guidelines where it is stated that :
"Your app should include features, content, and UI that elevate it beyond a repackaged website. If your app is not particularly useful, unique, or “app-like,” it doesn’t belong on the App Store".

But I am not sure whether Apple rejects such applications or not.
The same is for the Google Play Store.

Comment: Yes.  But if that is ALL your app does then it will likely get rejected by Apple.  Not sure how stringent Google is.

Comment: @Jason Lets say it also has a functionality to send push notifications or it contains a master-detail page(flyout page) where this web app shows in one of the menus, would it be accepted?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

Answer (score 0):

This question was already raised here:

[Will my app be rejected on Play Store or App Store because it is based on a WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62808291/will-my-app-be-rejected-on-play-store-or-app-store-because-it-is-based-on-a-webv)

I believe it will be rejected on the AppStore because it's a mere copy of a  website:

> 4.2 Minimum Functionality Your app should include features, content, and UI that elevate it beyond a repackaged website. If your app is not
> particularly useful, unique, or “app-like,” it doesn’t belong on the
> App Store.

It will possibly not be rejected by the Play Store if you are the [owner of the website linked in the app](https://playacademy.exceedlms.com/student/path/65190-comply-with-google-play-s-spam-and-minimum-functionality-policies):

> [...] if your app primary purpose is to drive affiliate traffic to a
> website or provide a webview of a site without permission from its
> owner, these behaviours aren't allowed.